# Plone: Upgrading jQuery

Tags: jquery, plone

Using the jQuery SlickGrid plugin with Plone 4.1 and trying to resize a grid column trips up [this jQuery 1.4.4 error](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7500), which has been fixed in more recent versions.

Is it possible to upgrade the core version of jQuery as used by Plone, and if so, how can this be done?

Comment: Just try to replace the jQuery library with a newer version? The latest version (1.7.1) is located here `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js`

Comment: It's the <i>how</i> that I'm asking about. jQuery is packaged up with Products.CMFPlone; if possible, I'd like to replace or override that version.

Comment: Oh, I was not aware of that. But I guess that if you check the package you'll be able to see the jQuery library. It's most likely in it's own file. Just rename it, place 1.7.1 in a file and give it the same name. It's shipped with jQuery Tools: http://plone.org/documentation/manual/theme-reference/page/using-jquery-and-jquery-tools

Comment: No, don't use 1.7.1.  IIRC, you need a version compatible with JQuery Tools, which Plone uses and many add-ons do as well.  Check plone-developers list -- I think someone is working on getting JQuery 1.6 working with Plone.

Comment: I've actually gone with using jQuery's noConflict option, and have a named install of 1.7.1 which is passed to the one JS widget that needs it. When I get some time toward the project end, I'll post the solution here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updating jQuery in Plone is not trivial because many scripts (including the integration of JQueryTools) depend on jQuery 1.4. JQuery is part of Products.CMFPlone. Thus, the update may break features.

Discussions are underway on the Plone developers mailing list about jQuery and jQuery UI.

Links on the Plone developers mailing list:

- http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/Upgrading-jQuery-and-jQueryTools-for-Plone-4-3-tt7070514.html#none - Upgrading jQuery and jQueryTools for Plone 4.3
- http://plone.293351.n2.nabble.com/JQueryUI-history-and-futur-and-sunburst-s-important-td7054219.html - JQueryUI history and futur and sunburst's !important

Comment: Thank you, but it was actually the first link that made me realise it might not be trivial and post here :) Given Plone loads jQuery as jQ, is it possible to run a second version as a dependency where needed?

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: No, any additional jQuery library would override any previously-loaded version. I'd expect things to break weirdly if you did that.

Comment: @MatthewTrevor: JQuery $.noConflict allows to have multiple JQuery versions in a same page. Example : http://aspnetnova.blogspot.com/2009/12/jquery-multiple-version-of-jquery-in.html

Comment: Accepted as the answer because I went with the `$.noConflict` solution

Answer (score 4):

You can override the library [jquery.js](https://github.com/plone/Products.CMFPlone/blob/master/Products/CMFPlone/skins/plone_3rdParty/jquery.js) quite easly (like any other file in a skin layer). You have 3 options for doing that:

1. the fast one: go to Zope Management Interface -> portal_skins -> custom and using the dropdown menu in the top-right corner add a new "File". Id = jquery.js, File = your desired jquery library.
2. the correct one: create a new package, [register a new skin layer](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/customization-for-developers/skin-layer-customisation) and put your jquery library in there (taking care of renaming it in "jquery.js" if necessary).
3. the other: [override that file using z3c.jbot](http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates_css_and_javascripts/skin_layers.html#nested-folder-overrides-z3c-jbot).

Do not edit the file in the file system directly as someone suggested: this is unnecessary and it's a very bad practice.

More info:

- http://collective-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/templates_css_and_javascripts/skin_layers.html