# Plone plone.app.jquery 1.9.1 breaks TinyMCE etc?

Tags: jquery, tinymce, plone

If i install a fresh Plone 4.3.2 and then upgrade the default plone.app.jquery from 1.7.2 to 1.9.1, editing the default homepage shows the following:
 - TinyMCE shows no toolbar
 - Form tabs no longer work
 - Javascript console errors:

```
 - TypeError: a.browser is undefined
jQuery.extend(jQuery.tools.overlay.conf,
popupforms.js (line 15)

 - TypeError: jQuery.tools.overlay is undefined
jQuery.tools.overlay.conf.oneInstance = false;
++reso...pers.js (line 16)

 - TypeError: jQuery.tools.overlay is undefined
jQuery.extend(jQuery.tools.overlay.conf,
popupforms.js (line 15)

 - TypeError: jqForm.children(...).tabs is not a function
$("input[name='form.button.PublishComment']").live('click', function () {
comments.js (line 146)

 - TypeError: $(...).live is not a function
$("input[name='form.button.PublishComment']").live('click', function () {
comments.js (line 146)
```

How can i use plone.app.jquery 1.9.1 with the latest version of Plone?

Comment: Upgrading jQuery between major versions, requires to execute migration-steps. Please see, if the [docs](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/) help you further.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Plone: Upgrading jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8427663/plone-upgrading-jquery)

Comment: If you want to be nice, leave notes about your debugging-results concerning Plone's core-components in this ticket: https://dev.plone.org/ticket/13959

Comment: Thank you very much for your report. Did the jQuery-docs help you to resolve the errors?

Comment: Thanks but I already understand the differences between jquery 1.7 and jquery 1.9 hence the reason i want to use it on my site. My custom packages have already been developed with an expectation that 1.9 is available, so you can see the frustration when it turns out that plone.app.jquery 1.9.1 appears to actually break Plone core functionality when you install it...

Comment: I didn't doubt you don't understand the difference, just hoped, you go right for fixing and share with us. Also this is not Plone-specific, any module using jQ has to face this on an upgrade. And as it's a delicate matter to foresee compatibilty-issues with other plugins. Anyway it's better to continue this discussion in the issue-tracker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the question "How can i use plone.app.jquery 1.9.1 with the latest version of Plone?" (currently 4.3.2) the answer appears to be:

1. It's not supported OR
2. You can try and configure your site to use a different editor (I actually did try CKEditor but same problem) or no editor (authors work directly in html), and disable popupforms and form_tabbing so there are no console errors OR
3. Dont rely on 1.9.1, instead develop your packages to work with jquery 1.7.2 until such time as Plone supports a higher version of jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your errors, probably you must update also plone.app.jquerytools to the version used by Plone 4.3 (see http://dist.plone.org/release/4.3.2/versions.cfg).

NBB: However I think that Plone 4.2 is not officially supporting jQuery 1.9.

Comment: 1. The latest Plone 4.3.2 ships with 
plone.app.jquery                      = 1.7.2
plone.app.jquerytools                 = 1.5.6

I have only updated plone.app.jquery to 1.9.1, so the plone.app.jquerytools remains pinned as shipped ie 1.5.6.

I could update this to the latest 1.5.7 but i dont think it will resolve the issues.

2. Why is there a package on pypi called plone.app.jquery (1.9.1) if it doesnt work with any version of Plone? 

3. Why isnt there a note at the plone.app.jquery pypi page saying what version it does works with ie none?

Maintained by esteele, garbas, davisagli, toutpt

Comment: Not exactly: I think that Plone 4.3 *can* work with plone.app.jquery 1.9. I only said about Plone 4.2

Comment: @AaronWilliams: Plone follow's the pythonic "Keep it modular"-approach, which means ideally each package is a little world of it's own, agnostic to what it's going to be combined with. The Plone-package on the other hand pins the compatible p.a.jquery-version down for you, which you can consider as the "note" you felt missing.

Comment: My point is that this package is released on pypi with no doco, other than it is from the core Plone team... with no wirte-up would you expect it to work with Plone or not? I would.

Comment: Look at the good write up for this other package (linked below) - it is clear what it works with. Thats all i'm asking for... Plone usage is going down over time and things like this don't help. http://plone.org/products/collective.js.jqueryui